# Unity 2018 - OnAudioFilterRead() realtime playback from buffer

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

Let me start by saying that this is my first time opening up a question here. If I'm unclear in my code formatting or have expressed myself poorly, please let me know and I'd be happy to adjust.

I'm doing conceptual design for a tool to be used in Unity (C#) to allow us to "stream" the output of an AudioSource, in real-time, and then have that same audio be played back from a different GameObject. In essence, we would have a parallel signal being stored in a buffer while the original AudioSource functions as one would expect, sending it's playing clip into the mixer just as is normal.

To achieve this I'm trying to use the audio thread and the OnAudioFilterRead() function. To extract the floating point audio data to pipe into OnAudioFilterRead() i'm using AudioSource.GetOutputData, storing that into an array and then supplying the array to the audio filter. I'm also creating an empty AudioClip, setting it's data from the same array and playing that AudioClip on the new GameObject.

Right now I have the audio being played from the new GameObject, but the result is very distorted and unpleasant, which i'm chalking up to one or more of the following;

1. The audio buffer is being written to/read from in an unsynched manner
2. Unitys samplerate is causing problems with the clip. Have tried both 44.1khz and 48khz with subpar results, as well as playing around with import settings on clips. Documentation for Unity 2018.2 is very weak and a lot of older methods are now deprecated.
3. Aliens.

Ideally, I would be able to stream back the audio without audible artefacts. Some latency i can live with (~30-50ms) but not poor audio quality.

Below is the code that is being used. This script is attached to the GameObject that is to receive this audio signal from the original emitter, and it has its own AudioSource for playback and positioning.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class ECO_receiver : MonoBehaviour {


public AudioSource emitterSend;
private AudioSource audioSource;    
public AudioClip streamedClip;

public bool debugSampleData;
private float[] sampleDataArray;
public float sampleSize;
public float sampleFreq;

private int outputSampleRate;
public bool _bufferReady;                         


void Start () {

    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    sampleSize = emitterSend.clip.samples;
    sampleFreq = emitterSend.clip.frequency;
    sampleDataArray = new float[2048];
    streamedClip = AudioClip.Create("audiostream", (int)sampleSize, 1, (int)sampleFreq, false);
    audioSource.clip = streamedClip;
    audioSource.Play();
    _bufferReady = true;
}

 private void FixedUpdate()
{

    if (emitterSend.isPlaying && _bufferReady == true)
    {
        FillAudioBuffer();           

    }
    else if (!emitterSend.isPlaying)
    {
        Debug.Log("Emitter is not playing!");
    }

    if (debugSampleData && sampleDataArray != null && Input.GetKeyDown("p"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sampleDataArray.Length; i++)
        {
        Debug.Log(sampleDataArray[i]);
        }

    }
    else if (sampleDataArray == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("No data in array!");
    }


}    

void FillAudioBuffer()
{

    emitterSend.GetOutputData(sampleDataArray, 0);             
    streamedClip.SetData(sampleDataArray, 0);
    _bufferReady = false;
}

void OnAudioFilterRead(float[] data, int channels)
{
    if (!_bufferReady)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = (float)sampleDataArray[i];           

        }

        _bufferReady = true;
        }
    }        


}
```

Greatly appreciate any wisdom I might be granted! Thank you!

Comment: Why `FixedUpdate`? It's proper to use the `Update` function here

Comment: I've gone back and forth between the two, I was afraid that Update might lag behind due to framedrops. But I see that it might still be the better choice to keep threads in sync!

Comment: Am I mistaken or are FillAudioBuffer and OnAudioFilterRead writing into the same audioClip? If it is, then you're writing the same data in to the same clip twice update

Comment: @JoakimSjoberg did you ever figure this out?